# how to get the mule application name

Tags: mule

Is there some way of getting the base mule application name of a deployed mule application?

The only two options i have found so far is:

```
muleContext.getConfiguration().getId() //which gives me some not so humanly-readable id of some sort.
```

and

```
muleEvent.getFlowConstruct().getName() //gives me that flow name from where this was called.
```

Each application is in their own application directory when deployed, is it not possible to get a hold of this or some other similar distinguished name from within the muleContext?

kind regards

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to retrieve the application name is by injecting it into your component using the `${app.name}` spring placeholder

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
String appName = ((org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader)this.getClass().getClassLoader()).getAppName();
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Mule 4.x** there are predefined variables and one of those is `app.name` to retrieve the **application name** in runtime. This is the link to the Mulesoft documentation to check all the predefined variables:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-variables-context

Answer (score 0):

For MuleSoft 4.2.0 you can load application name with static Java function:

```java
        ClassLoader cl = Class.forName("full-name-holding-this").getClassLoader();
        Method getArtifactDescriptor = cl.getClass().getMethod("getArtifactDescriptor");
        Object artifactDescriptor = getArtifactDescriptor.invoke(cl);
        Method getName = artifactDescriptor.getClass().getMethod("getName");
        Object appName = getName.invoke(artifactDescriptor);
        return appName.toString();
```